# .htaccess RewriteRule don't work

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

i've been searching on the apache website, stackoverflow's responses, and i couldn't find any answers to me..

All i want is to redirect `site.com/stats/` to `site.com/pages/stats.php` to make the path better and simple. as i said i've been searching it for a whole month, without any answer that could help me... I'm not english so sorry if i made mistakes on this question.

I'm actually on a VPS Debian 7 runing Apache version V2.2.22 (Debian)

My current rules (Maybe wrong ^^) are there :

`RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^stats/(.*)$ pages/stats.php <-- not working
RewriteRule ^player/(.*)$ pages/stats_player.p‌​hp?player=$1`

I'll really like who will answer this post

FOUND!
i just needed to add these 2 lines :

`RewriteRule ^stats/$ pages/stats.php
RewriteRule ^stats$ pages/stats.php`

Comment: `searching it for a whole month` That is a basic redirect not sure how it could take that long with the enormous amount of related questions. What are your current rules?

Comment: My current rules are :

`RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^stats/(.*)$ pages/stats.php <-- not working
RewriteRule ^player/(.*)$ pages/stats_player.php?player=$1`

Comment: i love how the formatting ruins all the text XD

Comment: @PanamaJack i will make a little reformatting: [Click here to see my current rules](http://pastebin.com/Hauisu60)

Comment: That's because you need **edit** your question and add the code there and not in the comments.

Comment: Done, i edited the question with all my current rules :)

Comment: @roro1506_HD - You'd have been a lot better off with this: http://hastebin.com/ixadireguf.apache

Answer (score 0):

Try this rule

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ pages/$1.php
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ pages/stats_player.php?$1=$2 [L]
```

Comment: it doesn't work :/ I don't know it it change something but i have a SSL Certificate (HTTPS). My RewriteRule for **player** is working, but when i add more rules, it don't work. Only **players** work :/

Comment: what more rules please explain.

Comment: as i said on the question, i currently have  rules. The one for "site.com/player/nameHere" and it redirects to "site.com/pages/stats_player.php?player=nameHere" the second is the one that don't work

Comment: currently i have these rules : [Click Here](http://pastebin.com/dpqYMh4h)

Comment: wait woops, i didn't see the order i putted them on, the "site.com/player/blablabla" is working, i'm searching for the "site.com/stats/"